# Google charts not rendering shows error as "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, google-visualization

I am using a directive to draw google line charts but it displays error like:

`Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string.`

I wanted to give color to a the line so I am using:

```
var seriesData = 
               [
                 ['Date', 'Percentage', { 'type': 'string', 'role': 'style' }]
               ];
```

But I think this is only taking as a string. So any help here how to solve this will me much appreciated. This is my full code:

```
googleChart.directive('doLineWithColorChart', ['config', '$filter', function (config, $filter) {

 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var _getSeriesData = function (series) {


            var seriesData = [
                ['Date', 'Percentage', { 'type': 'string', 'role': 'style' }]
            ];
            angular.forEach(series, function (data, key) {
                seriesData.push({ 'Date': new Date(data.BuildDateTime), 'Percentage': data.MetricValue, 'color': data.Status });
            });
            return seriesData;
        }



        var googleChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(element[0]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {

                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                },

                format: "MMM dd",
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#FFF',
                    fontName: 'Verdana',
                    fontSize: 11
                  },
                showTextEvery: 2
                },
            vAxis: {

                gridlines: {
                    count: 4,
                    color: '#FFF'
                },

                baselineColor: "#FFF",
                format: '#\'%\'',
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#FFF',
                    fontName: 'Verdana',
                    fontSize: 11
                   },
            },
            pointSize: 6,
            pointShape: {
                type: 'circle'
            },
            lineWidth: 2,
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },
            backgroundColor: '#000000',

            tooltip: {
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Calibri',
                    fontSize: 12
                }
            }
        };

        scope.$watch(function () { return scope.ngModel; }, function (xData) {

            var dt = _getSeriesData(scope.ngModel);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dt);

            googleChart.draw(data, options);

        });

    }

}


}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the below code for solving the issue

> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dt);

I have changed it to data.addcolumn(),data.addrows() format then it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what data looks like, but you populate `seriesData` with objects :

```
seriesData.push({ 'Date': new Date(data.BuildDateTime), 'Percentage': data.MetricValue, 'color': data.Status });
```

Instead you should populate it with arrays:

```
seriesData.push( [new Date(data.BuildDateTime), 
                  Number(data.MetricValue), 
                  data.Status ]);
```

Comment: This works but when it first loads it shows the same issue.After the data loads it render in the UI